# Creating dummy nodes for leetcode LinkedList questions

Tags: linked-list, nodes

I'm seeing a lot of solutions to these Leetcode LinkedList problems involve creating a dummy node, e.g.
[Example](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/solution/)

It seems to me that constructing this one additional ListNode object isn't a big deal and more importantly, considerably simplifies code. However, in my school, creating this kind of additional object is SEVERELY penalized.

I'm just wondering, is creating this extra dummy node acceptable in actual industry work? It makes code a lot more concise, yet is technically using extra resources

Comment: NB: the example link is only accessible for Leetcode subscribers. You might to use (and quote inside your question) another example.

Comment: At your school, if they give you a linked list assignment, including implementing a length method on the list, and asked you to compute the length of an empty list, how would it work?

Answer (score 0):

> is creating this extra dummy node acceptable in actual industry work?

Yes. Although there aren't that many examples I can think of where you would use linked lists in production code *and* would have to implement the linked list data structure yourself (as opposed to using an implementation provided by the programming language or a standard library that comes with it).

> It makes code a lot more concise

Yes

> ...yet is technically using extra resources.

Yes, but not more than when you would use two additional variables in your code. So this is not really an issue. A dummy node represents O(1) auxiliary space, which is what you would use anyway for iterating through a linked list using a node pointer/reference.

> in my school, creating this kind of additional object is SEVERELY penalized.

Too bad.

Comment: Isn't it even more essential than you imply here?  Without one extra allocation, how will I know the difference between an empty list and null?

Comment: That is more a question related to the data structure used. On LeetCode most (if not all) linked list questions represent a list by a head node reference, so then there is no difference between an empty list and null. If there is a separate LinkedList class instance (better IMHO than a dummy Node), with a head Node member, then you can have the distinction between an empty list or a null reference.

Comment: Without that distinction, I can't pass you an empty list to fill.  I guess I'd say, outside of the toy problem domain, OOP or not, we *allocate* a degenerate thing that represents an empty state.  I'm having trouble imagining a school that would teach otherwise.

Comment: @danh, *"I can't pass you an empty list to fill"*:  Actually you can in languages that support call-by-reference, like C++. These are details of programming languages, and the Asker has not marked this with a specific programming language.